# Maven vs. Gradle lib dependency difference

Tags: eclipse, maven, gradle, dependencies, multi-module

Given I've the following projects:

```
parent
--- common
--- child1 (depends on common)

unrelated (depends on common)
```

When both `parent` and `unrelated` are Maven projects and opened in the same IDE workspace (I verified in IDEA but I'm told that Eclipse behavior is the same), I can navigate from `unrelated` to `common` without having to link sources. Refactoring anything in `common` correctly finds references of it in `unrelated`. Since Maven doesn't differentiate between submodule and lib dependencies, both dependencies shown above are declared in the same manner.

With Gradle, `unrelated` doesn't seem to know that `common` exists in the same workspace. Refactoring anything in `common` breaks `unrelated`. The source code is only linked within submodules, as in between `child1` and `common`.

I'm looking at Gradle docs [23.8.3.3. Conditionally substituting a dependency](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:conditional_dependency_substitution),

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution.all { DependencySubstitution dependency ->
        if (dependency.requested instanceof ModuleComponentSelector && dependency.requested.group == "org.example") {
            def targetProject = findProject(":${dependency.requested.module}")
            if (targetProject != null) {
                dependency.useTarget targetProject
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However this only seems to work if the requested module is a subproject, which seems pointless, because if it were a subproject, we'd use a project dependency anyway, not a lib dependency.

Any idea how can I get the Maven like behavior in Gradle? Someone asked this in the [IDEA forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207423725-Resolve-Workspace-Artifacts-with-GRADLE-plugin-in-the-same-way-maven-is-supported) where he was told to create his own custom plugin. IDEA claimed that this feature is coming in 2016.3 version but they lied. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114469

Using Gradle 3.0, the latest. For full disclosure, I've also posted this question on Gradle forum.

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38945914/2211754) to similar question, and also specifically in your case for Eclipse check [this video demo](https://youtu.be/kSdlJDpUeWk?t=23m54s) (to do such things Buildship 2.0 plugin needed).

Comment: @VyacheslavShvets My test was done in IntelliJ not Eclipse but I was able to get this working using the Buildship v2.x beta.